# Drupal 7 - file.inc - file_put_contents(temporary://fileXXXXXX): failed to open stream

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, backend

Using Mac OS X Yosemite, Apache, PHP 5.5.14, MySQL 5.6.19, Drupal 7.32

Drupal failing to write due to bad file path. The bad file path is `temporary://fileXXXXXX`. I cannot understand why Drupal is failing to convert `temporary://` to `/tmp`.

I have configured the temporary files directory via Drupal admin UI, and confirmed it's modification in the DB...

```
SELECT * FROM variable WHERE name LIKE '%temporary_path';
+---------------------+------------+
| name                | value      |
+---------------------+------------+
| file_temporary_path | s:4:"/tmp" |
+---------------------+------------+
```

...and cleared caches just in case; however, to no avail. I've also confirmed the permissions on `/tmp` just in case: `drwxrwxrwt`.

As well, when switching back to my master branch via git *and* using a fresh copy of my DB (SQL dump from production) - the issue persists.

The errors are formatted as follows...

```
/.../includes/file.inc:1941 file_put_contents(temporary://fileXXXXXX): failed to open stream: "DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed
```

The issue is isolated to my local environment and is not effecting any shared environments; however, is thwarting my work progress. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: A couple of things to check...make sure there isn't a `$conf['file_temporary_path']` override in settings.php, and if you're using anything other than DB cache, clear it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, @Clive. I've fruitlessly grepped my entire code base for potential overrides. As well, there is only Drupal's generic cache running on my local machine, and I've cleared it many times without resolution. I've even gone as far as rebooting MySQL, Apache, and then my machine, and still nothing has solved it.

Comment: When you go to file settings admin page just click "Save" and if tmp files are writable nothing will happen. But if they are not fields containing not writible paths will get red outline. Is everything ok there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a tedious wade through multiple logs, I found this message...

`File temporary://filewFxsrd could not be copied, because the destination directory public://css is not configured correctly.`

...Knowing that my public file path was `sites/my-site/files`, I discovered that said directory did not exist, which lead me to this solution...

```
cd sites/my-site; mkdir files; chmod a+rwx files
```

...this is my local environment and the `files` directory is listed in our `.gitignore` so I'm not concerned with it's security; although, it is unclear to me how the directory was removed to begin with.

Thank you all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I went to admin/config/media/file-system and Saved the configuration. Then to admin/config/development/performance and Clear all caches. Voila the error message is gone.